# Where can I find debugging errors in my SSIS package?

Tags: sql-server, excel, debugging, ssis

After debugging my SSIS package (Excel file to SQL Server database) it tells me that I have surpassed the maximum number or errors (3) initially 1.

They suggested that I correct the errors or alter the Maximum error number.

Where can I find the debugging errors? If not how to change the maximum error number?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

> Where can I find the Debugging Errors ?

Look in the `Output` window of BIDS, or create an error handling routine to report errors to a table.

> If not how to change the Maximum error number ?

In the Properties of the package, under `Execution`, look for `MaximumErrorCount`

[image: Like so]

Comment: Happy to help out.